# Trying to Convert HTML and CSS with Bootstrap files to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

everyone. I created a homepage in PSD and then coded it using HTML with Bootstrap and CSS, but in the process of transferring everything onto WordPress, the page is all messed up. You can see it here:

http://www.mattriale.com/

This is what it should look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2OYq.jpg)

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>RialedUp</title>
        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
     <section class="hero-unit">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar">
            
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </a>
                      
                    <a href="#" class="brand">RialedUp</a>
                    
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end navbar -->
                    
            <div class="hero-unit-inner text-center">
                <h1>We build well designed websites</h1>
                <h4>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</h4>
                            
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Get Started!</a>
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                
                <img src="img/browser.png" alt="Browser" />
           </div><!-- end hero-unit-inner -->  
        </div>       
    </section><!-- end hero-unit -->
    
    <section id="process">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            
                <div class="h-line hidden-phone">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="plan text-center">
                        <span class="process-icon iplan">&nbsp;</span>
                        <h4 class="heading">Plan</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="design text-center">
                        <span class="process-icon idesign">&nbsp;</span>
                        <h4 class="heading">Design</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="develop text-center">
                        <span class="process-icon idevelop">&nbsp;</span>
                        <h4 class="heading">Develop</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="launch text-center">
                        <span class="process-icon ilaunch">&nbsp;</span>
                        <h4 class="heading">Launch</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>  
        </div>
    </section><!-- end process -->
    
    <section id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="p-item">
                        <h4 class="heading">Portfolio</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                        <strong><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="p-item">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img src="img/thumbnail/thumb-1.png" class="img-polaroid" alt="Web Design" />
                            <h5 class="title">LeafireDesigns</h5>
                            <small class="category">Web Design</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="p-item">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img src="img/thumbnail/thumb-2.png" class="img-polaroid" alt="Web Development" />
                            <h5 class="title">Unity</h5>
                            <small class="category">Web Development</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="p-item">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img src="img/thumbnail/thumb-3.png" class="img-polaroid" alt="Logo Design" />
                            <h5 class="title">Ingenious</h5>
                            <small class="category">Logo Design</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!-- end portfolio -->
    
    <section id="partners">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3 text-center">
                    <img src="img/thumbnail/partner-1.png" alt="Graphic Driver" />
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3 text-center">
                    <img src="img/thumbnail/partner-2.png" alt="Theme Forest" />
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3 text-center">
                    <img src="img/thumbnail/partner-3.png" alt="Code Canyon" />
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3 text-center">
                    <img src="img/thumbnail/partner-4.png" alt="Active Den" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!-- end partners -->
    
    <section id="widgets">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="testimonials">
                        <h4 class="heading">Testimonials</h4>
                                <img src="img/thumbnail/small-thumb-1.png" class="pull-left" alt="Moron" />
                                <blockquote>
                                    <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                                    <cite>Moe Ron <br />
                                    <a href="#">www.moron.com</a>
                                    </cite>
                                </blockquote>
                    </div><!-- end testimonials -->
                </div>
                
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="blog">
                        <h4 class="heading">Our Latest Posts</h4>
                        <ul class="blog-lists">
                            <li>
                                <h5><a href="#">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum</a></h5>
                                <small>October 4, 2017 | Posted by <a href="#">Admin</a></small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h5><a href="#">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum</a></h5>
                                <small>October 3, 2017 | Posted by <a href="#">Admin</a></small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h5><a href="#">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum</a></h5>
                                <small>October 2, 2017 | Posted by <a href="#">Admin</a></small>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- end blog -->
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="tweets">
                        <h4 class="heading">Latest Tweets</h4>
                         <ul class="tweet-lists">
                            <li class="clearfix">
                                <img src="img/thumbnail/small-thumb-2.png" class="pull-left" alt="Clown" />
                                <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor a iquet. <a href="#">http://this.is.me247</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                                <img src="img/thumbnail/small-thumb-2.png" class="pull-left" alt="Clown" />
                                <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor a iquet. <a href="#">http://this.is.me247</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                                <img src="img/thumbnail/small-thumb-2.png" class="pull-left" alt="Clown" />
                                <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor a iquet. <a href="#">http://this.is.me247</a></p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- end tweets-->
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </section><!-- end widgets -->
    
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            
                <div class="span12 text-center">
            
                <div class="table">
                <ul class="footer-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                
                <div id="social">
                    <a href="#" class="btn twitter"><span class="social-sprite twitter">&nbsp;</span>Follow Us on Twitter</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn facebook"><span class="social-sprite facebook">&nbsp;</span>Like Us on Facebook</a>
                </div>
                
                <small> &copy; <a href="#">Rialed Up </a>2017</small>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```css
body{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #7d7d7d;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'Museo';
    src: url('fonts/Museo700.otf') format('truetype');
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family: Museo, Rockwell, Serif;
    color: #333333;
}

a{
    color: #fb2f3a;
}

a:hover, a:focus{
    color: #eb2f39;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;  
}

.btn{
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #9a9c9f;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn:hover, .btn:focus{
    background: #8e9093;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.heading{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/** begin hero-unit **/

.hero-unit{
    padding: 0;
    background: url(img/hero-unit.jpeg) no-repeat 50% top;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-inner{
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.navbar .brand{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 177px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url(img/brand.png) no-repeat;
    line-height 100px;
}

.navbar .brand:hover{
    border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar .nav{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;  
    padding: 3px 20px;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a:focus, .navbar .nav > li > a:hover{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    border-bottom: none;
    background: none;
}

.navbar .nav > .active > a, .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus{
    box-shadow: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar .btn-navbar{
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
} 

.navbar .btn-navbar .icon-bar{
    background: #000;
    box-shadow: none;
} 

/** end hero-unit **/  

/** carousel controls begin **/

.carousel-control{
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 55px;
    top: 45%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.carousel-control:hover{
    border: none;
}

.carousel-control.left{
    left: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.carousel-control.right{
    right: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

/** carousel controls end **/

/** begin hero-unit-inner **/

.hero-unit-inner h1{
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.hero-unit-inner h4{
    color: #ccc;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.hero-unit-inner a{
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.hero-unit-inner img{
    margin-top: 0;
}

.hero-unit-inner .btn-primary{
    background: #fb2f3a;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: none;
    margin-top: 0;
}   

/** end hero-unit-inner **/

/** begin process **/

#process{
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 60px 0;
}

.h-line{
    max-height: 5px;
    background: url(img/h-line.jpg) repeat-x;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
    top: 55px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.process-icon{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: transparent url(img/process-sprite.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}

.process-icon.idesign{
    background-position: -100px top;
}

.process-icon.idevelop{
    background-position: -200px top;
}

.process-icon.ilaunch{
    background-position: -300px top;
}

/** end process **/

/** begin portfolio **/

#portfolio{
    padding: 60px 0;
}

.title{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.category{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
}

/** end portfolio **/

/** begin partners **/

#partners{
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
}

/** end partners **/

/** begin widgets **/

#widgets{
    padding: 50px 0 60px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.testimonials blockquote{
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
}

.testimonials blockquote p{
    font-family: Georgia, Serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #7d7d7d;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.testimonials blockquote cite{
    color: #333;
}

.blog-lists{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.blog-lists li, .tweet-lists li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.blog-lists li:first-child, .tweet-lists li:first-child{
    padding-top: 0;
}

.blog-lists li:last-child, .tweet-lists li:last-child{
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.blog-lists h5{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.blog-lists h5 a{
    color: #333;
}

.blog-lists h5 a:hover{
    color: #444; 
}

.tweet-lists{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.tweet-lists li img{
    margin-right: 20px;
}

/** end widgets **/

/** begin footer **/

.table{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

footer{
    padding: 60px 0
}

.footer-links{
    list-style: none;
}

.footer-links li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.footer-links li a{
    color: #666;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#social{
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.twitter{
    background: #569ccd;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.twitter:hover, .twitter:hover{
    background: #4f91bf;
}

.facebook{
    background: #2272ad;
}

.facebook:hover, .facebook:hover{
    background: #20699c;
}
.social-sprite{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent url(img/thumbnail/social-sprite.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: left-top;
}

.social-sprite.facebook{
    background-position: -26px top;
}

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px){ 
    .navbar .nav{
        float: none; margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    body{
        padding: 0;
    }
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .navbar .nav{
        float: none; margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    body{
        padding: 0;
    }
    .hero-unit-inner{
        padding: 0 40px;
    }
    .plan, .design, .develop, .launch, .testimonials, .blog, .tweets, .p-item{
        margin-bottom: 40px; padding: 0 40px;
    }
    #partners img{
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't your CSS.  If you check your console log for errors, you'll see that you have 18 errors.  It can't find your CSS files (or images).

You have to tell WordPress where to look.  The best way is by usinga a built in Wordpress function.  In this case, bloginfo.

```
 <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
```

which will automatically fill in your template url.

So for instance, instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
```

your code should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
```

You could, alternatively, hardcode it like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="www.mattriale.com/wp-content/themes/rialedup/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
```

but I would advise against that.  If you move your site to a different url, you'll have to go through everything again and change it.

If you're new to Wordpress, you might want to skim through this page.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference

Comment: Thanks, Eliezer. This is my first time using Twitter Bootstrap and creating a WordPress theme from scratch. In which php file should I place the code you gave me?

Comment: So, I inserted the code you gave me into the header.php file and it didn't change anything. Here's what I have in the header.php file:      

<?php wp_head(); ?>
        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
    
</head>
<body>
     <section class="hero-unit">
        <div class="container">

Comment: because you need to change ALL your css and image links to include it, and remove any links that don't.  In your code above, you added it correctly, but then right after, you still have the old link without it.

Comment: Okay. I'll try that and let you know what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. So I did what you suggested and it took care of almost all the errors! Plus, I had to go back into my footer.php file and add the /wp-content/themes/rialedup/ path in front of all my  src="/img/file.png" and that fixed all the "can't find image" errors. The only error I am receiving now is "couldn't load resource bootstrap.min.js", but I checked, and that file is in the js folder, right where it should be. Any way to fix that error? Also, how do I get rid of all the junk at the top of the page above my nav bar (the search bar, recent comments, archive, categories, and meta stuff)? Thanks

Comment: OMG! I just went into my dashboard and went to appearance/widgets and removed all the widgets that were putting all that stuff above my nav bar and when I refreshed my homepage, the default 2017 WordPress page appeared! I went to dashboard/appearance/themes and it's showing me this error message: "Broken Themes The following themes are installed but incomplete. Name Description rialedup/css Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a index.php template file. Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet." How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Okay. for anyone elese who may come across this problem, I figured out the solution. First, you need to have a Template Header at the top of your style.css file. Second, your style.css folder needs to be in your theme folder, NOT in a css folder. Once I did those two things the error message went away and I could activate my theme again.

Comment: Hey, Eliezer. I was able to get my homepage looking exactly like it should, but when I shrink the page down to iPad size, the navigation menu button doesn't open when I click on it. Obviously, this has to do with the "couldn't load resource bootstrap.min.js" Javascript error I mentioned earlier. Is there any way to fix this issue? Also, the black WordPress Admin bar isn't showing up at the top of the page when I am logged in. Any way to fix that issue as well? Thanks.

Comment: This is the Javascript in my footer.php file: <script src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Please mark the question as answered.  I have answered the original question.  If you have further questions, please put them as a separate question, or try and figure it out on your own.